# Allow empty string to turned into null Date in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm looking to allow a `th:field` that collects a date via the [BootStrap DatePicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to be empty.

What I run into is a validation error since it is empty, and it looks like this:

`Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.annotation.Nullable java.util.Date] for value '';`

Perhaps I don't quite understand the `@Valid` annotation well enough to know how to do this.

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: can you add you entity class that you are validating?

Answer (score 0):

can you elaborate more on this error, I was having same error but in different scenario so wanted to understand the flow of error so I can share solution i did.

Comment: I resolved my issue by adding `BindingResult` parameter after my `@Valid` parameter. I have no idea why it works, but it does